# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'display'

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, class

I am attempting to write a program that randomly assigns numbers to three different lists and then, with the help of different classes, calls the function "display()", and displays various results. I've got my classes and the loop with the randomization down, but every time I try to print display() results, I get an error saying there is no attribute 'display'. I've tried changing variable names to see if that would help but the error persists.

My code goes:

```
    class Circle():
    def __init__(self, radius=1):
        self.__radius = radius

    def find_area(self):
        a = self.__radius * self.__radius * 3.142
        return(a)

    def setRadius(self, rad):
        self.__radius = rad

    def getRadius(self):
        return(self.__radius)

    def display(self):
        print("\nClass = Circle")
        print("The area for this circle is:\t")
        return(self.find_area())

class Square():
    def __init__(self, sside=2.3):
        self.__sside = sside

    def find_area(self):
        a = self.__sside * self.__sside 
        return(a)

    def setSSide(self, lw):
        self.__sside = lw

    def getSSide(self):
        return(self.__sside)

    def display(self):
        print("\nClass = Square")
        print("The area for this square is:\t")
        return(self.find_area())

class Cube():
    def __init__(self, cside=2):
        self.__cside = cside

    def find_surfacearea(self):
        sa = 6 * self.__cside * self.__cside
        return(sa)

    def setCSide(self, lwh):
        self.__cside = lwh

    def getCSide(self):
        return(self.__cside)

    def display(self):
        print("\nClass = Cube")
        print("The area for this cube is:\t")
        return(self.find_surfacearea())

x1 = Circle()
print(x1.display())

x2 = Square()
print(x2.display())

x3 = Cube()
print(x3.display())

#Lists and Loops
circlelist = []
squarelist = []
cubelist = []

circlecount = 0
squarecount = 0
cubecount = 0

for i in range (10):
    shape = random.randint(1, 3)
    number = random.randint(0, 10)

    if shape == 1:
        print("\n*Circle*")
        circlecount += 1
        circlelist.append(number)

    elif shape == 2:
        print("\n*Square*")
        squarecount += 1
        squarelist.append(number)

    else:
        print("\n*Cube*")
        cubecount += 1
        cubelist.append(number)

"""x = len(circlelist)
y = len(squarelist)
z = len(cubelist)

for i in range (x):
    circlelist[i].display()
    #print()

for i in range (y):
    squarelist[i].display()

for i in range (z):
    cubelist[i].display()"""

print("\nThe items in the circle list are:", circlelist)
print(len(circlelist))
print("The items in the square list are:", squarelist)
print(len(squarelist))
print("The items in the cube list are:", cubelist)
print(len(cubelist))

for i in range (len(circlelist)):
    circlelist[i].display()

"""for i in range (10):
    circlelist.display()
    squarelist.display()
    cubelist.display()"""
```

Could someone help me see where I might be going wrong?

Comment: circlelist is a list of numbers (`circlelist.append(number)`). Numbers don't have a display() function.  Your 3 classes have that function, but you can't use that function outside of an object that you create with that class.

Comment: So how would I go about using display() for each of the numbers in the lists? I'm relatively new to this.

Comment: Do you just want to display the number, or do you want to run that function you have in your class?

Comment: I'd like to run the function that is in my class. I'm able to print the lists with all the items in them, but I don't know how to call the classes and use them for these items.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and see if that answers your question

Comment: I've been trying to run your code, and it looks like I might have more issues than I originally thought. The print statements from the functions are now showing up, but they're appearing in a constant loop (circle, square, cube) as opposed to the random order that I hoped to get, and the return(self.find_xyz) is still not working. My output also now says that the list index is out of range even though that hasn't changed at all.

Comment: If you want to print as they are being created (in a random order), call `self.display()` in the `__init__` function of each class.

Comment: Like def __init__(self, radius=1, self.display()): self.__radius = radius? That seems to be giving me a syntax error and highlighting the period between self and display.

Comment: no, I just updated by answer with what I was talking about for the init function on the bottom.

Comment: That did fix the order, thank you. But my program is still not giving me any real numbers in the output, do you think that might be because my data is private and simply appending the numbers to the lists might not be working?

Comment: Are you talking about the output of the display() function, or something else?

Comment: Yes, the output for display(). It shows the two print statements, but nothing where the result for the return statement should go.

Comment: Oh I see now. I just copied over your code so I could actually see what is happening.  `return` statements are not printed.  You probably want to do something along the lines of `print("The area for this circle is:\t {}".format(self.find_area()))` for the second print statement, and get rid of the return statement.

Comment: That works, thank you so much!

Comment: do you mind accepting my answer since it answers the original question you had? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your lists are simply lists of numbers. You can't run the `display()` function on numbers, it has to be run on one of your objects.  This requires a relatively simple change. Rather than have a list of numbers, have a list of objects.

In the code below, I changed it so rather than appending a number to the list, it appends a new object with the random number as the radius,sside,cside as appropriate.

```py
for i in range (10):
    shape = random.randint(1, 3)
    number = random.randint(0, 10)

    if shape == 1:
        print("\n*Circle*")
        circlecount += 1
        circlelist.append(Circle(radius=number))

    elif shape == 2:
        print("\n*Square*")
        squarecount += 1
        squarelist.append(Square(sside=number))

    else:
        print("\n*Cube*")
        cubecount += 1
        cubelist.append(Cube(cside=number))
```

How to edit `__init__` functions to display upon creation:

```py
    def __init__(self, radius=1):
        self.__radius = radius
        self.display()
```